# Не определяется элемент класса

Tags: c++, ооп

**FIGURE.H**

```
#ifndef FIGURE_H
#define FIGURE_H

class Figure {
public:
    virtual double Square() = 0;
    virtual void   Print() = 0;
    virtual ~Figure() {};
};

#endif
```

**TSTACKITEM.H**

```
#ifndef TSTACKITEM_H
#define TSTACKITEM_H

#include "FIGURE.H"
class TStackItem {
public:
    TStackItem(const std::shared_ptr<Figure> &obj);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const TStackItem &obj);

    std::shared_ptr<Figure> GetFigure() const;
    std::shared_ptr<TStackItem> GetNext();

    virtual ~TStackItem();
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Figure> item;
    std::shared_ptr<TStackItem> next;
};

#endif
```

**TSTACKITEM.CPP**

```
#include "TSTACKITEM.H"
#include <iostream>


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const TStackItem &obj){
    os << obj.item << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

Здесь упорно выделяет красным item в obj.item

И пишет, что класс TStackItem не содержит члена item

Почему так - я же прописал: *std::shared_ptr item;*

Как исправить?

Comment: @Harry, пишет именно <<class "TStackItem" не содержит члена "item" >>

Comment: Можете описать, что делать поподробнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело было в том, что я забыл подключить библиотеку *#include < memory >*